# how do i disable click on particular item in list view

Tags: json, flutter, api

i want to disable click on some items in list view ,
from api i can get some list of item

like

```
[
  {
    "date": "1",
    "click": "1"
  },
  {
    "date": "2",
    "click": "0"
  },
  {
    "date": "3",
    "click": "1"
  },
  {
    "date": "4",
    "click": "0"
  },
  {
    "date": "5",
    "click": "2"
  }
]
```

I want to disable `onclick` with flutter if `click = 0`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

define your own child widget for list view item as follow:

```
  Widget myWidget (String date, String isEnable){
    return RaisedButton(onPressed: isEnable=="1"?YourFunction:()=>{}, child: Text(date),);
  }
```

the use in `ListView.builder` as follow:

```
return ListView.builder(itemBuilder: (ctx, idx){
      return myWidget(yourList[idx]["date"], yourList[idx]["click"]);
    }, itemCount: yourList.length,)
```

where `yourList` is the given list in your question. Also, you can use any form of widget instead of RaisedButton, it is just an example!